# Including plus sign in preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I would like to parse a string in this format ++VAR++.

I have tried the preg_match_all("++.*?++", $input, $matches); but failed.
I am missing something?

Comment: How did it fail? Surely, you missed the regex delimiters. Do you have strings like `++++++++++` that you do not want to match? Try [`preg_match_all('~(?<!\+)\+\+(\w+)\+\+(?!\+)~', $txt, $matches);`](https://regex101.com/r/xI3gM5/1). See [demo](http://ideone.com/riy5mj).

Comment: Did you check the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You missed to escape the + and also forgetted to add php delimiters.

```
preg_match_all('~\+\+.*?\+\+~', $input, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is missing **[regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)**. Besides, `+` is a special regex metacharacter (a *one or more* quantifier), it must be escaped to be treated as a literal character.

If you only have alphanumeric characters to match inside *only double* plus symbols, you can use

```
preg_match_all('~(?<!\+)\+\+(\w+)\+\+(?!\+)~', $txt, $matches);
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xI3gM5/1).

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/riy5mj):

```
$re = '~(?<!\+)\+\+(\w+)\+\+(?!\+)~'; 
$str = "I have ++VAR++ and  +++++++++++ and +++text+++++ and ++ANOTHER_VAR++."; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```